# How to add authorize direct post method to one step checkout in magento?

Tags: authorize.net, onestepcheckout

How to add authorize direct post method to one step checkout in magento?

http://prntscr.com/agdco5

Here, i add screen cast of my one step checkout page.
i enable authorize direct post method but in not works in one step checkout.

when i click on place order button it will place new order at admin >> sales >> order

but don't see cc form.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should require support from your vendor to work on your issue as soon as possible. Because I am using One Step Checkout from [mageplaza.com](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-one-step-checkout-extension/), it works very well. This is the screen cast of one step checkout on my website.

[image]